# "POST is not allowed" error on IBM Graph in BlueMix

Tags: ibm-cloud, graph-databases

I'm trying to create the schema on IBM Graph Data Store but I'm receiving "POST is not allowed" error. See code below:

```
ricarez@oc3038028384 ~]$ curl "https://ibmgraph-alpha.ng.bluemix.net/
4f92b002-1e10-4f49-93f7-b9835b8daf91/schema" \
      -X POST \
      -u "$username:$password" \
      -d '{"propertyKeys": [{"name": "DBVid", "dataType": "Float", "cardinality": 
                             "SINGLE"},
                            {"name": "Oid", "dataType": "Integer", "cardinality": 
                             "SINGLE"},
                            {"name": "Name", "dataType": "String", "cardinality": 
                             "SINGLE"}],
           "vertexLabels": [{"name": "Person"},
                            {"name": "City"},
                            {"name": "is_part_of"}],
           "edgeLabels": [{"name": "origin", "multiplicity": "MULTI"},
                          {"name": "plays_at", "multiplicity": "MULTI"}],
           "vertexIndexes": [{"name": "vByDBVid", "propertyKeys": ["DBVid"], 
                              "composite": true, "unique": false},
                             {"name": "vByOid", "propertyKeys": ["Oid"], 
                              "composite": true, "unique": false},
                             {"name": "vByName", "propertyKeys": ["Name"], 
                              "composite": true, "unique": false}],
           "edgeIndexes": [{"name": "vByDBVid", "propertyKeys": ["DBVid"], 
                            "composite": true, "unique": false},
                           {"name": "vByOid", "propertyKeys": ["Oid"], 
                            "composite": true, "unique": false},
                           {"name": "vByName", "propertyKeys": ["Name"], 
                            "composite": true, "unique": false}]}' \
      -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
{"code":"MethodNotAllowedError","message":"POST is not allowed"}
```

Any idea on how to solve that?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `/g/` in your URL. It should be `https://.../g/schema`

Comment: Thanks a lot.
That was the issue.